# Defining delimiters in mysql

Tags: mysql, delimiter

I am having trouble with creating a stored procedure in mySQL. I think the issue is that it is seeing my delimiter as a string, but I may be wrong. Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getOrderInfo (IN whichorderID int)
BEGIN
    SELECT hslineitem.orderId, hsorders.orderdate, hslineitem.partNum, hslineitem.numOrdered,
            hslineitem.price
    FROM hslineitem, hsorders
    WHERE hslineitem.orderId = hsorders.orderId
    AND orderID = whichorderID ;
END 
//
DELIMITER;
```

[image: errormessage]

So, is there a specific way I need to identify that it is a delimiter and not a string? I have been looking at other examples online and it doesn't seem that they do anything differently. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. How are you running this query? 2. Why did you choose `//`? Did you try something else, such as `$$`?

Comment: just switch delimiter back to what it was before ;-) . :-)  `END // DELIMITER ;`

Comment: $$ did not work either. Those were the only two examples provided to me by my book, and also the only two I found online.

Comment: Alex, could you elaborate further on what you mean by what it was before? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Is it possibly just a missing space between "DELIMITER" and the last semicolon?

Comment: Oh my god, yes. If I could facepalm on here, I would. Thank you so much--I cannot believe of all the things, it was a space. Sigh.

Comment: Well thats logical: "DELIMETER" is a command and needs to be separated from its parameter ";" by a space, right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Got caught up in all the big stuff and missed the small stuff. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You statement is missing a space before the last semicolon, because the semicolon in this case is really a parameter for the `DELIMITER` command.

Only after resetting the delimiter back to semicolon it can be used normally:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getOrderInfo (IN whichID int)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM orders
    WHERE id = whichID;   -- this semicolon is interpreted as text
END//
DELIMITER ;               -- space is needed here!
SELECT 1 FROM dual;       -- but not here.
```